# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() - Troubleshooting

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, database-connection, sqlsrv

**System Information**

CMS: Wordpress

Web Server: XAMPP

PHP Version: 5.5.30

MS Management Studio 17

**Goal**

Establish MSSQL Database connection using PHP

**What has been done**

1. Downloaded SQLSRV Drivers
2. Copied files **php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll** and **php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll** to the directory `C:\xampp\php\ext`
3. Added the following lines to the dynamic extensions part in the php.ini file: `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll`
4. Restarted Web Server
5. Confirmed sqlsrv is listed in phpinfo()

**Code**

```
$serverName = "technology-pc\sqlexpress";

// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"example_db");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
} else {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

**Error**

> Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have added the PDO variant of SQLSRV drivers to the extension list, but have not added the base drivers `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`.

Add to the php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

or

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

---

Also, you really should be using either the Thread-Safe (`_ts.dll`) or Non-Thread-Safe (`_nts.dll`) versions of the driver, not both. I believe that, as you are using an Apache Server, you should be using the Thread-Safe versions. So you php.ini should have:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You probably edited the wrong php.ini file. Check the right php.ini file with php info.

You can use this script:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Or if you have CLI access type php -i to get the info listed.
Check for the right path of your php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to connect mssql database

```
$server = 'dburl.com\MSSQLSERVER, 1433';
$username = 'uname';
$password = 'password';

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password,"ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo);
```