# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in WAMP 32 bit

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, fatal-error, sqlsrv

I think this might be duplicate question but I think I tried all of resolution available but still seeing this error.

I have simple php program to connect to SQL Server database when I run that I am seeing the error message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
>   C:\wamp\www\Samples\sqlconnect.php on line 5

I am able to connect to MYSQL but not to SQL SERVER.

Following are the things I tried:

1. I have currently WAMP 32 Bit on windows 10
2. PHP version 5.6.25
3. I have downloaded and added Microsoft driver for PHP for sql server SQLSRV32.EXE  in wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext
4. There are 2 files created in that folder now

php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

5. I have added these files into my php.ini.
6. I was previously using WAMP 64bit but someone had suggested that the error is due to 64bit wamp version so I uninstalled it and installed 32 bit version.
7. Still I am seeing the same error message.
8. I also tried this
   Someone had also suggested there will be 2 php.ini files one in apache so I used this path in my php.ini file still getting error

extension=C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts‌​.dll extension=C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nt‌​s.dll

Please tell me how can I connect to SQL Server Database.

```
<?php
$servername     = "name\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Document", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"mypass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $servername, $connectionInfo); <!--GETTING ERROR FOR THIS LINE -->
    if($conn)
{
    echo "Connected. <br/>";
}
else
{
    echo "Connection Failed. <br/>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
echo "ho";
?>
```

Comment: Someone also suggested there will be 2 php.ini files one in apache so I used this path in my php.ini file still getting error                   extension=C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function sqlsrv\_connect() - Troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677399/call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-troubleshooting)